# Problem 2.6 from Isaacs "Character Theory of finite groups"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to prove the following problem (Isaacs "Character Theory of finite groups" 2.6):

> Let $\chi, \psi$ be characters of $G$. Define $\chi\psi : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$  by $(\chi \psi)(g) = \chi(g)\psi(g)$.
>
> a) If $\psi(1) = 1,$ show that $\chi\psi$ is a character.
>
> b) If $\psi(1) = 1,$ show that $\chi\psi \in Irr(G)$ iff $\chi \in Irr(G).$

a) Let $\varphi$ be a representation of the character $\chi$. Let's define the following representation $\stackrel{\sim}{\varphi}:$

$$\stackrel{\sim}{\varphi}: G \rightarrow GL_{n}(\mathbb{C})$$
$$g \stackrel{\stackrel{\sim}{\varphi}}{\rightarrow} \psi(g)\varphi(g)$$

This is really a representation, since $$gh \stackrel{\stackrel{\sim}{\varphi}}{\rightarrow} \psi(gh)\varphi(gh) = \psi(g)\psi(h)\varphi(g)\varphi(h)$$ (since $\psi$ is a linear character and $\varphi$ is a representation).

Then this representation will correspond to the character $\chi\psi$.

Are the arguments given here correct?

b) Suppose that the character $\chi \psi$ is irreducible. Then

$$[\chi \psi, \chi \psi] = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi \psi(g)|^{2} = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi(g)|^{2} |\psi(g)|^{2} = 1 \geq \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi(g)|^{2} > 0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi(g)|^{2} = 1.$$

But how to prove the opposite statement?

I will be very grateful for any help.

Comment: a) No, this doesn't work. Since $\psi$ is just a character $\psi(gh) \neq \psi(g) \psi(h)$. The representation you need to construct is called the tensor product and it uses representations whose characters are equal to both characters involved.

Comment: I apologize for the possibly a not very smart question, but in this case the character $\psi$ is linear. That is, $\psi$ is just a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{C^{*}}$

Comment: Oh, I see,, I missed the $\psi(1) = 1$. My bad. In that case this is fine.

Comment: Your work looks fine, For (b) you've shown $\chi$ irr implies $\chi\psi$ irr, the opposite direction follows from the very same implication, but multiplying $\chi\psi$ by $\psi^{-1}$ to get $\chi$ (reciprocal not functional inverse).

Comment: @runway44
I think I understand what do you mean. $1 = [\chi, \chi] = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi(g)|^{2} = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi(g)\psi(g)\psi^{-1}(g)|^{2}  = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi\psi(g)|^{2}|\psi^{-1}(g)|^{2} \geq \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi\psi(g)|^{2} >0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|G|}\sum\limits_{g\in G}|\chi\psi(g)|^{2} = 1?$

Comment: Actually now that I'm looking at your comment, and looked back at your question, I see you're introducing inequalities. But why are you writing inequalities? A number being $>0$ does not imply a number $=1$, and you need $=1$ to conclude irreducibility. Plus, it seems like your inequalities are based off of character values having $|\cdot|^2\ge1$. This is not true about character values in general. Though for 1D characters, it is not only true, but we can (and must) say something better: $|\cdot|^2=1$.

Comment: Isaacs' book states that for any characters $\chi, \psi$ the inner product $[\chi, \psi]$ is a non-negative integer. Therefore, if I am not mistaken, based on these inequalities, we can say about equality to unity. 

I just don't quite understand why it is possible to guarantee the equality of all these expressions in my proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your part (a) is fine. Keep in mind $\psi(g)$ is scalar-valued, which is why it commutes with everything.

For part (b), don't bother with inequalities. Since $G$ is finite and $\psi(g)$ is scalar-valued, if $m$ is the order of $g$ we can say $\psi(g)^m=\psi(g^m)=\psi(e)=1$ so $\psi(g)$ is an $m$th root of unity and in particular, $|\psi(g)|=1$ for all $g\in G$. Thus, when you write out the formula for $\langle\chi\psi,\chi\psi\rangle$, you will find it *equals* the formula for $\langle\chi,\chi\rangle$, so one is $=1$ iff the other is, so $\chi\psi$ is irreducible iff $\chi$ is.

Comment: Oh yes, now I understand.  Thank you very much for help!